# "pubg" instead of "PUBG" - case sensitive input question

Tags: python

I am doing some homework for a course called introduction to programming. 
I am making a small lookup application with a dictionary list.
I am just curious to what I can do to make it so that the user can type for example "pubg" instead of "PUBG"? I have tried .lower() everywhere but because I don't really understand how it works I don't know what I need to change.

```
import sys
while True:
    print("-" * 45)
    print("\n" "Welcome to game creator lookup!")





    game_list = {
            "Battlefield" : "EA DICE",
            "Fortnite" : "Epic Games",
            "Counter strike" : "Valve",
            "PUBG" : "PUBG Corporation",
            "Overwatch" : "Blizzard",
            "Dota" : "Valve",
            "Call of duty" : "Infinity Ward",
            "The sims" : "EA, Maxis, Firemoney studios"}



    choice = (input("What game would you like to look up? (Type 'q' to quit) " "\n"))
    if choice in game_list:
        print (choice, "was created by", game_list[choice])

    if choice == ("q"):
        print("goodbye")
        sys.exit()

    elif choice not in game_list:
        print("Invalid choice, try again")
```

Comment: Please post your code that uses .lower() everywhere as you tried to use it so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite game list this way:

```
game_list = {
        "battlefield" : ("Battlefield", "EA DICE"),
        "fortnite" : ("Fortnite", "Epic Games"),
        "counter strike" : ("Counter strike", "Valve"),
        "pubg" : ("PUBG", "PUBG Corporation"),
...
```

(in fact this rewrite could be done automatically with an appropriate function)

Then you can use

```
choice = choice.lower()

if choice in game_list:
    print (game_list[choice][0], "was created by", game_list[choice][1])
```

Comment: You only need to rewrite the keys to all lower case.Not the entire list.

Comment: @fullern000 Then the output would also contain the game name all lowercase. If this isn't a problem, you are right.